# Elmah.MVC + NLog - store all errors in one place

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nlog, elmah, elmah.mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 app in Visual Studio 2015. We use NLog to write some errors and other information to the database in our `try/catch` blocks. However, it would be nice to also implement [ELMAH.MVC](https://github.com/alexbeletsky/elmah-mvc), so that any/all uncaught exceptions get caught/logged and the user redirected to a friendly page.

Here's our NLog table structure; note that `ApplicationId` is not equivalent to `Application` on the `ELMAH_Error` table; people apply for things through the app, and this is the ID we assign when they start the process. And `RouteId` is not an MVC route.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [int] NULL,
    [RouteId] [int] NULL,
    [MachineName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LogLevel] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Logger] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [StackTrace] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The SQL for ELMAH's table looks like this (from [the script here](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/elmah/ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql)):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error]
(
    [ErrorId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Application] NVARCHAR(60)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Host]        NVARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Type]        NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Source]      NVARCHAR(60)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Message]     NVARCHAR(500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [User]        NVARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [StatusCode]  INT NOT NULL,
    [TimeUtc]     DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Sequence]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AllXml]      NTEXT COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
) 
ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Is it possible to have the `ELMAH_Error` table contain the additional columns found on the NLog `Log` table, or vice versa? How can I write errors from NLog to the ELMAH table?

Thank you.

**Update 1:** Came across this: https://github.com/ccellar/nlog-elmah-target, but it lacks any documentation on how you use it. Would this redirect all NLog exceptions to ELMAH?

**Update 2:** A [related question](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah/issues/162) has been asked about adding the `Exception.Data` dictionary to ELMAH. This way, any number of key/value pairs can be added to what Elmah stored. This way, all the data now stored with NLog would be stored on ELMAH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that works very nicely: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Elmah/

To install,

1. `Install-Package NLog.Elmah`
2. `Update-Package NLog`
3. I also installed NLog.Web package, but isn't required for this.
4. Modify NLog.config to include:

```xml
<targets><target name="target1" xsi:type="Elmah" LogLevelAsType"false" /></targets>
    <rules><logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="target1" /></rules>
```

Now just decorate any controller/class that uses NLog with the target:

```
[Target("Elmah")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Other code...

        var logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, _logger.Name, "Some information...");
        _logger.Log(logEvent);

        // Other code...
    }
}
```

You can also throw the attribute on a base controller/class and cover all your application.

Comment: I do this exactly but nothing gets logged to Elmah (elmah logging works and nlog logging to a text file works, though).. am i missing something?

Comment: @benpage, did you try steps on here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Elmah/?

Comment: Found the problem - i was using the elmah bootstrapper instead of elmah.mvc - when using elmah mvc, you need to specific `errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah"` in web.config. With the boostrapper you don't, and .GetDefault(null) was returning the InMemory iteration of elmah rather than the SQL one.

Comment: @benpage, glad you figured it out.